# rc.local python script unrelated error: "getrandom indicates that the ..."

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

**rc.local**

```
/home/pi/home/gate/run.sh &

exit 0
```

**/home/pi/home/gate/run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/pi/home/gate
export CREDENTIALS=credentials.json 

sudo -E -H -u pi sh -c 'python3 localclient.py > log.txt 2>&1'
```

all I get in log.txt (update - plus some of my debug prints, initially I forgot to set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1):

```
getrandom indicates that the entropy pool has not been initialized. Rather than continue with poor entropy, this process will block until entropy is available.
```

also I'm using `sudo` because `su - pi` didn't work (I got import errors, maybe because it didn't set $HOME?)

If I run `run.sh` manually (that is not automatically on startup), it works.

Also, the process uses all of the cpu (while blocking until more entropy?) and the pi gets hot.

Comment: The reason it works when running manually is that the system has had enough time to gather sufficient entropy for encryption to work securely. As for how to fix it, it would depend on which sources of entropy are connected to the device and how quickly they seed (which I don't know details around).

Comment: @I0b0 But it blocks (somehow busily? all cpu usage) even long after boot. At the times, when running it manually works. I would expect it to start working after a while based on that error message.

Comment: I tried `sleep`ing 180 seconds before running the script and it did not help. It must be something else than the time. Perhaps the environment? I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, sometimes, running it manually also produces the error and not always the cpu usage is 100 %. But still, I haven't observed the script recovering from the error and working.

Comment: Waiting 10 minutes works so far (the error does not appear). Still I should test, if it recovers from the error (run it without sleeping) after say those 10 mins.